# Is there any way to make compiled ASP.NET website impossible to decompile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, compilation

Is there any way to compile ASP.NET Web Site and make it impossible to decompile (reverse engeenering)?

I wrote my own big project in Visual Studio, I want to compile it and sell to the buyer. But I don't want buyer to see/modify the source code in any way. I'm worried because even though I published (compiled) it with "allow this pre-compilled web site to be updatable" unchecked, I heard about something like Reflector and ways to get the source from binaries.

Is there any way to make it impossible? It's all about piracy prevention - I added fixed line of code that makes the website working only on ONE particular domain like XXXXXXX.XXX (typed in the code). But I'm worried that it can be decompiled and this line can be removed.

Thanks